# Providing template parameters for a member variable

Tags: c++, templates

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>
#include <array>

// default function for array
std::function<double(int, int)> f_default = [](int num1, int num2) {return num1 / num2; };
//


// alias declaration
template <unsigned instruction_count, typename output, typename... input>
using instruction_set = std::array<std::function<output(input...)>, instruction_count>;
//

template <unsigned instruction_count_, typename output_, typename... input_> 
class environment {
public:
    instruction_set<instruction_count_, output_, input_...> instructions = {f_default};
    output_ run_first(input_... args) {
        return instructions[0](args...);
    }
};


int main()
{
    std::function<double(int, int)> first = [](int num1, int num2) { return num1 * num2;  };
    environment<1, double, int, int> env;
    env.instructions.at(0) = first;
    std::cout << env.run_first(5, 5);
}
```

Output:

```
25
```

Please note: this is just a quick example of the problem i'm facing that i whipped up in 5 minutes.

I have the alias `instruction_set`, which is the type of the member variable `instructions` of class `environment`. In order to provide the template arguments for `instructions`, I have to pass them through the class instantiation... but is this not bad? What if I have many member variables with template arguments I need to provide?

It would be very unorganized and confusing, even with just one member variable which requires template arguments. So, my question is: **Is there any better way to provide template arguments to member variables?**

Comment: I’ve heard about template template parameters but don’t understand how they’d be used here.

Comment: I may have misundertood your meaning. But in general a class should be templated with all the parameters required to instantiate it. In particular it should include all parameters required for members which are themselves templated. I don't see another way around it in the general case.

Comment: That’s what i’ve been thinking, too. But what if I have a class with like 5 member variables with 3 or 4 template parameters each? That’s a ludicrous amount of unorganized arguments being thrown into the class template parameters.

Comment: If the 5 members are independent (and use independent template paramerers), then I don't see a way around it at the moment. Let's see if somebody comes with a better solution.